# OAuth 2 Script Error

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0, dropbox

My application is WPF, written in C# in VisualStudio 2017, using the Dropbox API v2.

I'm trying to obtain an `AccessToken` for Dropbox and am following the OAuth 2 code on the Dropbox developer's website: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleTest

My issue is I am receiving a Script Error when the Dropbox Login page loads. The error is:

> Line: 0, Char: 0, Error: Script Error, Code: 0, URL:
>   https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/compiled/js/alameda_bundle/alameda_bundle.min-vflHAZfb_.js

I m sure my `redirect Uri` is correct and registered because I changed my default web browser from Edge to Explorer and then to Chrome, and each time the log-in worked once (and returned a token) but then threw the same error. The scripting error is now thrown on any of my browsers. I've checked the security settings and scripting is enabled on all.

Here's the XAML:

```
<local:DropboxBrowser Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                      AccessToken="{Binding AccessToken, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      UserId="{Binding UserId, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Result="{Binding Result, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And the key parts of my method:

```
    private void WebBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith(REDIRECT_URI, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            OAuth2Response result = DropboxOAuth2Helper.ParseTokenFragment(e.Uri);
            if (result.State != _oauth2State)
            {
                return;
            }

            AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
            UserId = result.Uid;
            Result = true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

I'm developing with an MVVM architecture, but for now I've reduced my code to a straight lift from Dropbox's example - hence the horrible mix of bindings and code-behind, but I'll sort that out once I have the authentication working.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: I have the same issue with a previously working code. Seem to be the problem in on the Dropbox's side.

Comment: @AndreyShcherbakov, that's a blow ... did you come up with any workaround solutions?

Comment: No workaround yet. I posted this on their support forum:
https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Authentication-error-on-Windows-alameda-bundle-min-vflHAZfb-js/m-p/274323#M16331

Comment: @AndreyShcherbakov, thanks, be interesting to hear what they have to say. My feeling is it's something to do with version of IE being used in Webbrowser control. If you're interested, I replaced my webbrowser control with a CefSharp control (http://cefsharp.github.io/) and authentication now works ... does have drawbacks though.

Comment: Thanks for the reports! This does seem to be due to the underlying browser/version used by the web view and its compatibility with the Dropbox site. For this reason, we do now highly reccomend only using a supported system browser and not a web view. Ambie, I'm glad to found workaround. I'll follow up on the forum thread though.

Comment: @Greg There is another issue. Now it takes more than 20 seconds for the auth page to render. No matter what internal browser is used WebBrowser or CefSharp. The same URL loads immediately in a standalone Chrome browser, but has same almost 20 seconds delay in Microsoft Edge.

 

Here is an example URL:

https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=ovbydhrxqbsjkqc&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fauthorize&state=13dfc7e4b30b490b94d45189e14a18ab

Comment: @AndreyShcherbakov I see you also posted about this on the forum so I'll follow up there.